# is there a way to kill a hive job without killing the AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I use AWS EMR cluster to run HIVE query. For query optimization purpose, sometime I need to kill a long-running step but keep the EMR cluster live so I can keep using it. Is there a way to do it either in HIVE CLI or AWS console?

Comment: I think it always shows the cancel command to be used. Read the debug output when you start the Hive command and see if you can find it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Thanks for your response. I just googled and found an answer from ASW website. The only thing is that AWS does not allowed to stop a running step. Please see below

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-work-with-steps.html) for the detail. To cancel steps using the AWS CLI:

aws emr cancel-steps --cluster-id j-2QUAJ7T3OTEI8 --step-ids s-3M8DKCZYYN1QE

Comment: This will only cancel steps which are not in RUNNING state. Any way to stop the states which are running ? @Jason